# Lost network connection while downloading s3 client within promise.all()

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, promise

I am working on a nodejs-based server that downloads 1000 pdf files each 9MB from s3, compresses them into a zip file, and returns the URL.

However, a problem is occurring while downloading from S3.
When I start downloading on S3, About 100 downloads are downloaded and then Internet connection is not possible.
Looks like its not related to size, because it was successful when trying with 5 files with 1GB file.

This causes mysql connection lost > transaction fail `[ERROR] Error: BEGIN; - Can't add new command when connection is in closed state`
[lost connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARUPR.png)

I suspect that heavy network operations should not be placed inside promise.all(), but I don't know the exact cause. Help!

```
await Promise.all(
  Ids.map((id) => {
    const readablePayloads: Array<{ filename: string; bugffer: Readable; }> = [];
    // get key, bucket by id
    
    const buffer = await S3Helper.getReadable({bucket, key} {accessKeyId, secretAccessKey});
    readablePayloads.push({ filename, buffer });
  })
)
```

```
static async getReadable(opts: { bucket: string; key: string }, awsOpts: AwsOptions): Promise<Readable> {
    return (await createS3Client(awsOpts).send(new AWS.GetObjectCommand({ Bucket: opts.bucket, Key: opts.key }))).Body as Readable;
  }
```

for sure, this code worked less than about 100 connections

Answer (score 0):

I see few possible causes of this problem:

- File descriptor limit.
  Any open connection uses file descriptor(s). Linux's default limit of [file descriptors per process is 1024](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19476-01/821-0505/file-descriptor-requirements.html#:%7E:text=Linux%20systems%20limit%20the%20number,worker%20threads%20will%20be%20blocked.). So there is't much you can do about it, except forking your node.js process or increasing the limit. The latter is not really recommended unless you have really good reasons. Another way is to just limit the number of connections, which i'll cover below.
- Memory Heap limit.
  This one is less probable, but still: every open connection uses some amount of memory. Moreover, depending on how you write your code and handle the readable streams you might have excessive amount of buffering in readable streams or even memory leaks.

##### Limiting the number of connections

Download your files in smaller groups, not all at once. It might look something like this:

```js
// _.chunk comes from the `lodash` library.
// Now `chunksOfIds` is an array of arrays, each of which contains up to 100 ids.
// i.e [[1,2,...,100],[101,102,...,200],...,[1001,1002,...,1100]]
const chunksOfIds = _.chunk(Ids, 100)

for (const chunk of chunksOfIds) {
  const readablePayloadsOfThisChunk: Array<{ filename: string; bugffer: Readable; }> = [];

  chunk.map((id) => {
    // get key, bucket by id

    const buffer = await S3Helper.getReadable({bucket, key} {accessKeyId, secretAccessKey});
    readablePayloadsOfThisChunk.push({ filename, buffer });
  })


  // Note: you have to process your `readablePayloads` here, in the loop,
  // so that you will finish your computations before the processing of the next chunk will start
  await processReadablePayloads(readablePayloadsOfThisChunk)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.
I solved the problem in a similar way. The difference is that I added Promise.all() to map().
Also, one of the causes I identified was using the Readable type. Even though I limited it to chunks like your solution, I think the Readable type is holding the connection on the s3Client side until the stream completes.
Therefore, for now, we are using the Buffer type, but there may be further updates due to speed issues.